# How to find a path for a Blob in Postgres

Tags: database, image, postgresql, path, blob

I am in the process of decommissioning a postgres database that has tens of thousands of blob files in it. The original setup of this database did not scale well, storing thousands of image files as blobs. The process now is to push the database files to slower storage and disable the database server.

I would like to be able to work out how to extract these image files by their blob ID, if such a thing is possible.

I know that, in general, the files are stored in:

```
/<path to postgres>/pg_data/base/<database_oid>/
```

However the files in there do not correlate to the blob's ID within the database. Is there a query I can run that will give me a mapping from OIDs to file paths or am I misunderstanding how the files are stored on disk?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I did misunderstand how data is stored.

Postgres stores Blobdata as a collection of byte arrays and then references to them. It is non-trivial to re-construct the files from this.